# Reading From/Writing To an Access Database in VB.Net 2010

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, read-write

I have been working on this for a few days now and I have checked two or three books I have laying around for VB.Net 2003 and the method to do this has changed. Also, I have searched this website for other answers to the same, and found a reference to the MSDN that said something about a ConnectionString. I could not find decent documentation on the ConnectionString, and the rest of the method given was useless without it, so now I must ask... How can I read and write to and from an Access database file in VB.Net 2010?

Comment: You could start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carl Prothman has lists of connections strings for just about every occasion:

http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=87#OLEDBProviderForMicrosoftJet

http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Access has two versions, ACE and Jet.

Comment: nice...wish I would have known about that carlprothman site 10 years ago :)

Comment: ohkay, so how do i determine which version the database i'm using was saved as? I'm assuming Jet is the default...? or no?

Comment: You can use ACE for both Jet (mdb) and ACE (accdb) files. Up to Access 2007, the default is Jet, after that, it is up to the user.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/simpledbreadwrite.aspx?pageflow=FixedWidth